# Remove non alphanumeric from string but keeping encoded non-ASCII characters åäö

Tags: python, regex, encode, python-2.x, non-ascii-characters

How can I keep åäö but remove all other non alphanumeric chars from a string? 
(I found similar questions but none seem to have a proper answer.)

I tried stuff like extending the regex to try making it skip åäö in the sub but it seems to just make the regex stop working all together letting whitespaces and such stay aswell.
I'm not usually programming in python, just trying to help a friend out, so there might be some better way to clean a string than using re.

From googling I think it has to do with Unicode, but no good solutions.

```
def ordnaText(text): 
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub('\W', '', text)
    if text.isalnum() == True:
        return text
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: What is `type(text)`?

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you mean Eric, but its a string? from raw_input

Comment: @A.collin: That is an important piece of information.

Comment: @A.collin: When you add the line `print type(text)` to the code, what is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match against *encoded* input; `raw_input()` in Python 2 always returns a byte string. This means that the terminal, console or IDE you are using determines what encoding is used for the input.

Trying to match non-ASCII characters with a regular expression, using byte strings requires you to match the *encoded* bytes exactly, which usually means that any change in the terminal environment or your source code editor settings will lead to the match failing.

You want to explicitly decode the `raw_input()` here, and use Unicode matching:

```
import sys
import re

def ordnaText(text): 
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(u'\W', '', text, flags=re.UNICODE)
    if text.isalnum() == True:
        return text

userinput = raw_input('....')
userinput = userinput.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
something = ordnaText(userinput)
```

`sys.stdin.encoding` tells you what Python thinks the input codec is. Using `flags=re.UNICODE` specifically switches on unicode support in the regular expression engine. And `u'\W'` gives the engine a Unicode string literal; the latter is optional but it is better to be explicit.

If you want to learn more about Unicode, encoded byte strings and how it relates to Python, I recommend you read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `\W` with `[^\wåäö]`.

However the test `text.isalnum` will return false if the string contains an accentued character.

Comment: yes, I tried that and for some stupid reason is removes åäö still :S

Comment: @user2225454: Strange! I have tested it with pythex.org and it seems to work.

Comment: Are you using `u'[^\wåäö]'`?

Comment: `u` tells python "This is a sequence of unicode code points, not a sequence of bytes"

Comment: Note that you're still likely to have a bad time - try it on the string `ääa`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use flag `re.UNICODE` in `re.sub()`